# Working with CspParameters

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have sample code that stores key in container. But I see only container name set. Where is key storing procedure? How to load key from container?

```
UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("MySecretData!");
string containerName = "SecretContainer"; 
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters() { KeyContainerName = containerName }; 
byte[] encryptedData; 
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp)) 
{ 
 encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false); 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass `CspParameters` with `KeyContainerName` set to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, its `PersistKeyInCsp` property is set to `true` accoring to [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.persistkeyincsp(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The PersistKeyInCsp property is automatically set to true when you
>   specify a key container name in the KeyContainerName field of a
>   CspParameters object and use it to initialize an
>   RSACryptoServiceProvider object by calling one of the constructors
>   with a parameters parameter.

With that property set - provider will first check if container with such name exists. If it does - it will use key from that container. Otherwise it will create container and store its key there. Since you didn't provide specific key - a random pair of keys will be generated and stored in container. When you next time use csp with the same container name - that generated key will be used.

If something is not clear, run the following code:

```
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var containerName = "MyContainer";
        var original = "MySecretData!";
        var encrypted = Encrypt(containerName, original);
        var decrypted = Decrypt(containerName, encrypted);
        Debug.Assert(decrypted == original);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string Encrypt(string containerName, string data) {
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters() { KeyContainerName = containerName };
        // random key is generated and stored in new created container with provided name
        // since it does not exist yet
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp)) {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false));
        }
    }

    static string Decrypt(string containerName, string data) {
        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters() { KeyContainerName = containerName };
        // here container already exists so key from that container is used            
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp)) {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(data), false));
        }
    }
}
```